# CountDownTimer is not stopping on BackPressed running in background,may be handler.postDelayed() is the issue. How to fix it in this code?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

My Countdown timer is working fine but when I use back press during running state of the time, my countdown timer did not stop. I have tried everything as follows but none of them is able to stop the countdown timer from running in the background. After searching the forum an applying the results from it to my project I am unable to figure out whats fault in my code. Please anyone help me out and I shall be very thankful.

```
    public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLIS = 30000 ;

    List<Questions> mQuestions;
    int score = 0;
    int qid = 0;
    Questions currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestions, textViewCountDown;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
    Button btnNext;
    private QuestionsViewModel questionsViewModel;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    private ColorStateList textColorDefaultCd;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private long timeLeftInMillis;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            takeAction();

        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        textViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.profileLoadingScreen);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearView);
        textColorDefaultCd = textViewCountDown.getTextColors();


        fetchQuestions();

        questionsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(QuizActivity.this).get(QuestionsViewModel.class);

        questionsViewModel.getAllQuestions().observe(this, new Observer<List<Questions>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Questions> words) {
                // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                mQuestions = words;
                //Collections.shuffle(mQuestions);
                Collections.addAll(mQuestions);

            }
        });

    }



    private void fetchQuestions() {


        DataServiceGenerator dataServiceGenerator = new DataServiceGenerator();

        Service service = DataServiceGenerator.createService(Service.class);

        Call<List<QuestionsModel>> call = service.getQuestions();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<QuestionsModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<QuestionsModel>> call, Response<List<QuestionsModel>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    if (response != null){
                        List<QuestionsModel> questionsModelList = response.body();

                        for (int i = 0; i < questionsModelList.size(); i++){
                            String question = questionsModelList.get(i).getQuestion();
                            String answer = questionsModelList.get(i).getAnswer();
                            String opta = questionsModelList.get(i).getOpta();
                            String optb = questionsModelList.get(i).getOptb();
                            String optc = questionsModelList.get(i).getOptc();

                            Questions questions = new Questions(question, answer, opta, optb, optc);

                            questionsViewModel.insert(questions);
                        }

                        handler = new Handler();//add this
                        handler.postDelayed(runnable,3000);

            /*    Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                takeAction();

                            }
                        }, 3000); */




                    }

                }else{

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<QuestionsModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void setQuestionView()
    {
        txtQuestions.setText(currentQ.getQuestion());
        rda.setText(currentQ.getOptA());
        rdb.setText(currentQ.getOptB());
        rdc.setText(currentQ.getOptC());
        qid++;


    }

    private void startCountDown() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timeLeftInMillis = 0;
                updateCountDownText();
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

        String timeFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

        textViewCountDown.setText(timeFormatted);

        if (timeLeftInMillis < 10000) {
            textViewCountDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            textViewCountDown.setTextColor(textColorDefaultCd);
        }
    }



    private void takeAction() {
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        textViewCountDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        timeLeftInMillis = COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLIS;
        startCountDown();



        currentQ = mQuestions.get(qid);
        txtQuestions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        setQuestionView();
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

                if (grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Select an Answer",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;

                }else{
                   // countDownTimer.cancel();

                }

                RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                grp.clearCheck();
                //Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());

                if(currentQ.getAnswer().equals(answer.getText()))
                {
                    score++;
                    Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
                }else{

                }
                if(qid<10){
                    currentQ=mQuestions.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(handler!=null){
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;

        }
        finish();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(handler!=null){
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        if (countDownTimer!=null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;

        }
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(handler!=null){
           handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        if (countDownTimer!=null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;

        }
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (countDownTimer!=null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }
        finish();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if(handler!=null){
       handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
    if (countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;
    }
    finish();
 }
```

Comment: Sir this code also i have already tried and it is also not working. @Shehroz